# Accessing the component's values when using `<ng-content>`

Tags: typescript, angular

Looking for a method to access the component's values when using `<ng-content>`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  template: `<person-box>{{name}}</person-box> <!-- something like this -->`
})
export class HomePageComponent {
  // missing code?
}
```

Component's code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'person-box',
  template: `<div style="background-color: blue;"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`
})
export class PersonBoxComponent {
  name = 'Katharina Muster';
}
```

(Above example is of course very simplified.)

---

When using `@ViewChild` it works:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  template: `<person-box>{{box.name}}</person-box>`
})
export class HomePageComponent {
  @ViewChild(PersonBoxComponent) box: PersonBoxComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ContentChild(PersonBoxComponent) box:PersonBoxComponent;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this.box);
}
```

Comment: Hi Günter. `@ContentChild(PersonBoxComponent)` is not working (console output is undefined) but `@ViewChild(PersonBoxComponent)` does.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look properly at the class name

Comment: No worries about the class name. ;) But do you know by chance, why `@ContentChild` is not working for me but `@ViewChild`does?

Comment: If `@ViewChild()` is working then you seem to have added the code to a different component than I expected. Can you please add more code to your question that demonstrates what you're doing?

Comment: What value do you actually access from where?

Comment: Sorry for my late response... I'm accessing data of a child component from a parent component in order to use them within a `<ng-content>` section of the child component.

Comment: Currently I've solved the problem with event binding.